# Limitations for creating a security application on Windows Phone

Tags: security, windows-phone-7, alarm, background-agents

I am actually trying to create an application for Window Phone that could create an alarm if a specific event happens : a security application that could create an alarm if the power cord is disconnected to inform the user that his phone has been taken.

I need to create an alarm that can only be stopped using my application (for example, by using a specific password). I need for my application to run in the background while the user can use the phone. My application cannot be closed other than using my application and specifying a password.

Doing so, I found the following limitations :

- I cannot find how to create an alarm that could be activated even if the vibrate mode of the phone is activated other than using the Alarm class. The problem is that I need to keep the alarm active while I did not stop it using my application. The problem is that using an Alarm object, the user can easily stop the alarm.
- I cannot run my application in the background because the actions that a background application can do are really limited (Background agents). My application should be able to react to the event at any time which is not possible using a background agent.
- I cannot stop my application from being closed. I need for the user to have to use, for example a password, to be able to close my application.

I looked for information on the forums and in the different documentations and did not find any solution.

I just would like to know if I am right and there are actually no solutions to these problems and this application cannot be created on Windows Phone, or if I missed something and it is possible.

I know that it is a lot of questions but I would really appreciate if one of you could find some time
to shed some lights.

Thanks in advance

Laurent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is, simply put, **not possible**. And it's not going to be possible either. And your requirements are breaking with almost every single marketplace certification requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much Claus for the confirmation and for taking the time to answer my questions :).